# Redirect not showing the redirected component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-dom

I am trying to redirect user on a condition. My component is like

```
const App = (props:any) => {

function handlecandidatelogin(e:any) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let isError = false;
}
if(!isError){
  props.history.push("/instructions")
} 
return (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <LoginPage 
        candidatedetails={candidatedetails}
        handlecandidateadd={handlecandidateadd}
        handlecandidatelogin={handlecandidatelogin}
        buttonDisable={buttonDisable}
        nameError={nameError}
        emailError={emailError}
        mobileError={mobileError}
        />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/instructions">
        {/* <Instruction
          candidatedetails={candidatedetails}
          handlecandidateadd={handlecandidateadd}
        /> */}
        <Instructions/>
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/test">
        <Test />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
    {/* <MsgCard img={image} text="Your screen would be shared all the time" width="30%" /> */}
    {/* <Switch>{routeComponents}</Switch> */}
    {/* <Header /> */}
    {/* <Switch>{routeComponents}</Switch> */}
  </Router>
);
}
export default withRouter(App);
```

I had wraped my app component in BrowserRouter as well. It's showing me localhost:3000/instructions on url but it's not rendring the instructions component.
All needed packages has been imported.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have commented out your `Instruction` component:
**Remove** `/* */`  from your code.
From this:

```
<Route exact path="/instructions">
        {/* <Instruction
          candidatedetails={candidatedetails}
          handlecandidateadd={handlecandidateadd}
        /> */}
        <Instructions/>
      </Route>
```

To this:

```
<Route exact path="/instructions">
        <Instruction
          candidatedetails={candidatedetails}
          handlecandidateadd={handlecandidateadd}
        />
        <Instructions/>
      </Route>
```